# how do I open pg_hba.conf?

Tags: postgresql

I'm installing and running a postgres server on a Ub12.04 server.

Could anybody help me in finding the syntax to open the pg_hba.conf to accept any connection from any host?

I tried

```
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

The "listen_addresses" parameter is correctly set to "*", and the server rebooted after changes.

Comment: Didn't know Postgres had an error message `no luck`.

Comment: showing the actual error message prevents this from being a guessing game. Also showing all uncommented lines in your pg_hba.conf would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess: you need to set [`listen_adresses`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-connection.html#GUC-LISTEN-ADDRESSES)

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

in postgresql.conf.
There is not enough information in your question to do more than guessing.

Comment: The "listen_addresses" is correct. The error I get clearly indicates the pg_hba.conf file.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have restarted your server properly after changing this file. Also make sure you enable the right listen-addresses in your postgresql.conf file.

Comment: Restarting the server is not necessary. A `pg_ctl reload` is absolutely enough.